# hide selected option in select box

Tags: jquery, html-select, show-hide, fadeout

I noticed strange behaviour with **form select** element and jQuery **.fadeOut** / **.hide**

I have simple **select** box:

```
<select name="categories">
  <optgroup label="Choose option:">
    <option selected="selected" value="placeholder">CHOOSE OPTION</option>
    <option value="category-books">Books</option>
    <option value="category-music">Music</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

And with jQuery I wanted to remove **option:selected** (my way to emulate placeholder in this kind of  box) when user click **select** with this code:

```
$('select').click(function() {
    $('option[value=placeholder]').fadeOut('slow');
});

$('select').blur(function(){
    $('option[value=placeholder]').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

This code in Firefox works and **option** smoothly fades out after  is clicked, but in other bowsers (IE9, Opera, Chrome) this does'nt work :-[ Here You can check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/cachaito/Xy7DF/3/

I tried **.remove** (works) and **.hide** (doesn't) but I wanted an animation to hide this element...

PS. Do You know better way to fadeIn **option** element when user leaves **select** box (focusout works the same way like .blur)?

Answer (score 1):

Try Changing

```
$('option[value=placeholder]').fadeOut('slow')
```

with

```
$('option[value=placeholder]', this).fadeOut('slow')
```

This is what I do in my code to hide an "option"

```
$('#mySelect option[value=' + myVal + ']').hide().siblings().show();
```